# Python Recursion Behavior

Tags: python, recursion

I have studied recursion, especially in Python, and think I get it.
I have learned this form:

```
def f_Listsum(numList):
   if len(numList) == 1:
       return numList[0] ## Triggers the unwinding of the recursion stack
   else:
       return numList[0] + f_Listsum(numList[1:]) ## Winds up the recursion stack with a shorter and shorter slice of org. list.
```

I get it. The recursive calls sort of "wind" things up, and then a stop or "trigger" causes the recursion to collapse into itself and consume the resulting values.

However I ran into this today:

```
def f_DecToBinary(v_Num):
    if v_Num > 1:
        f_DecToBinary(v_Num // 2)
    print(v_Num % 2,end = '')
```

I wanted to substitute the function's "print" with a return of a string, or even a list of INTs, but I can't get it to work, as I don't understand how this recursion is operating. I see that it calls itself each time, and then initiates a collapse when v_Num == 1 or less, but it collapses to outside the "if" statement and then I get lost. When I try to assemble a STR or LIST from the collapse instead of just printing it, I errors or just the last digit returned.

My questions are: How does f_DecToBinary work/function, and how can I capture the output into a string?

Some examples:

```
print(f_Listsum([1,3,5,7,9])) ## 25
print()
f_DecToBinary(15) ## 1111
```

Thanks

Comment: // , The way that you worded "The recursive calls sort of "wind" things up, and then a stop or "trigger" causes the recursion to collapse into itself and consume the resulting values." suggests that you have had the chance to look at where and how recursive functions break. How did you go about inspecting their values, @JayJay123?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def DecToBinary(n):
    if n >= 2:
        return DecToBinary(n // 2) + str(n % 2)
    else:
        return str(n)
```

Comment: I appreciate your question. It's useful to understand recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the typical flow through the function. It will call itself, which causes some output, then it prints a single digit. So the single digit comes at the *end* of the previous ones. To return the result instead of printing it, you need to take the result of the recursive call and add the current result to the end of it.

Comment: Thank you that was of some assistance.